What kind of cable is this?
I'm doing an installation at a friends house, needing to get network access into the garage. I noticed they have this cable running in. Is it an older kind of network cable?
Thanks!



any markings on the sheath? with 8 conductors it's likely thermostat wire

No markings! Unfortunately I haven't been to the site yet so these pictures are all I have to go on

If all you have is pictures from a site you have not been to, there may well be markings on the sheath that are not obvious in pictures (or one suspects, covered with white paint from the cable being present when the place was sprayed white, inferring from the picture.) Might become more obvious if you can find the other end, might remain a mystery.

Hard to tell from such a blurry pic, but that kinda looks to me like it might be stranded cable, which wouldn't be used for any kind of normal residential telecom purpose, except maybe some kind of old security system.

Running ‘in’ from where? Is there a sprinkler system?

Thermostat seems most likely as mentioned by @ratchet freakthough the color coding is slightly off standard for that.
Not a networking cable of any age, in my experience.
Possibly a serial terminal cable if it's not thermostat wire and you want to run with "old computer wiring" as a theory.
Or just "random multi-conductor cable" with former purpose unknown. Some former person with access to multi-conductor cable wanted to hook up speakers in the garage from the stereo in the house, or whatever.
I'd give it very low odds for running network on.

it's possible to attach a rj45 connector to that and treat it like a ethernet cable but I wouldn't expect top end speeds from it. though if you can pull an actual cat5 or cat6 you will get better speeds.

Thanks guys! I think safest bet is just to pull another cable.

I strongly suspect you'd have a fun time trying to attach an RJ45 as my read on the pictures (such as they are) is that it's considerably fatter cable & wires and might be stranded to boot. Running new cable is definitely the better bet.

May want to add a line about network cables (or at least for Ethernet) require twisted pairs, which are almost certainly not the case for this cable. I used to use Cat 3 cable for serial terminals - but never the older cables (low-capacitance shielded but no twisted pairs) for Ethernet.
